What is the difference between _final() and _destroy() method in nodejs (custom writable implementation)
I am currently learning nodejs streams and I came across custom nodejs writable stream implementation. But I am getting trouble understanding what is the difference between _final and _destroy method.
After doing some searches I found that _final method will be called after Stream.end() method is called and _destroy method will be called when an error is occurred or stream.destroy() is called. And all the resource clean-up is done inside _destroy method. But what if I don't call stream.destroy() or no error is occurred in the stream? Will the file resource be not closed? Will it remain opened?

What's not clear? For _final()... "This optional function will be called before the stream closes, delaying the 'finish' event until callback is called.". For _destroy()... "The _destroy() method is called by writable.destroy()".

The key difference between _final() and _destroy() in a custom Node.js writable stream implementation lies in when and why they are called, as well as their intended purpose:

_final()
When it's called: _final() is invoked when the stream's end() method is called, signaling that no more data will be written to the stream.
Purpose:
Used to perform final cleanup or processing tasks before the stream is fully ended.
Common tasks include flushing any remaining buffered data or closing a file resource if the stream is writing to a file.
Behavior: After _final() completes (calling its callback or resolving the returned promise), the stream emits the finish event.

_destroy()
When it's called: _destroy() is invoked when the stream is destroyed explicitly by calling destroy() or if an error occurs, which causes the stream to be destroyed.
Purpose: Used to clean up resources like file descriptors, database connections, or sockets that are associated with the stream.
Handles cleanup after errors or intentional destruction of the stream.
Behavior: After _destroy() completes, the stream emits the close event.



Example Usage

    const { Writable } = require('stream');
    class MyWritable extends Writable {
        constructor(options) {
            super(options);
        }

        _write(chunk, encoding, callback) {
            console.log(`Writing: ${chunk.toString()}`);
            callback();
        }

        _destroy(err, callback) {
            console.log('Stream is being destroyed:', err || 'no error');
            callback(err);
        }
    }

    const writable = new MyWritable();
    writable.write('Hello, ');
    writable.destroy(new Error('Something went wrong')); // Triggers _destroy()

`

This explanation effectively highlights the key differences between _final() and _destroy() in custom Node.js writable streams. It clearly addresses when each method is called, their respective purposes, and their impact on stream behavior. However, it could be beneficial to include a practical example or code snippet to illustrate how these methods are typically implemented and used in real-world scenarios. This addition would make the explanation even more comprehensive and actionable for readers.
